# React + Express sending data?

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm working on a login/register system with React front-end and Node/Express back-end.

When the registration fails, i want to reload the registration page and return the error msgs to my react front end.
Instead of refreshing the page, it renders the JSON data.

How can you go about re-rendering the registration form, while sending the data behind the scenes?

```
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {

const { name, email, password, password2 } = req.body;
  let errors = [];
...
...
...
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.send({
      errors,
      name,
      email,
      password,
      password2
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to receive the response from express in your react app, and perform your logic inside your submit function in react.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to create a state variable for the error message. Make the initial value null or ''. When user registration fails catch the error and assign it your error variable in state. Here is an example of user registration system:

```js
//RegistrationForm.js


import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AuthApiService from '../../services/auth-api-service';
import { Input } from '../Utils/Utils';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import './RegistrationForm.css';

export default function RegistrationForm(props) {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const errorDiv = error 
        ? <div className="error">
            <i class="material-icons error-icon">error_outline</i>
            {error}
          </div> 
        : '';

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setError(null);
        
        const { full_name, user_name, password } = e.target;

        AuthApiService.postUser({
            full_name: full_name.value, 
            user_name: user_name.value, 
            password: password.value
        })
            .then(user => {
                full_name.value = '';
                user_name.value = '';
                password.value = '';
                props.onRegistrationSuccess();
            })
            .catch(res => {
                setError(res.error);
            })
    };

    return(
        <form className='RegistrationForm'
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >  
            <div className='full_name'>
                <label htmlFor='RegistrationForm__full_name'>
                    Full name
                </label>
                <Input
                    name='full_name'
                    type='text'
                    required
                    id='RegistrationForm__full_name'>
                </Input>
            </div>
            <div className='user_name'>
                <label htmlFor='RegistrationForm__user_name'>
                    User name
                </label>
                <Input
                    name='user_name'
                    type='text'
                    required
                    id='RegistrationForm__user_name'>
                </Input>
            </div>
            <div className='password'>
                <label htmlFor='RegistrationForm__password'>
                    Password
                </label>
                <Input
                    name='password'
                    type='password'
                    required
                    id='RegistrationForm__password'
                    >
                </Input>
            </div>
            <div className='confirm-password'>
                <label htmlFor="LoginForm__confirm-password">
                    Retype Password
                </label>
                <Input
                    name='confirm-password'
                    type="password"
                    required
                    id="LoginForm__confirm-password">
                </Input>
            </div>
            {errorDiv}
            <Button type='submit' variant='contained' color='default'>
                Register
            </Button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

```js
//AuthApiService.js

import config from '../config';
import TokenService from './token-service';
import IdleService from './idle-service';

const AuthApiService = {
    postUser(user) {
        return fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/users`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
            .then(res =>
                (!res.ok)
                ? res.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e))
                : res.json()
            )
            .then(res => {
                TokenService.saveAuthToken(res.authToken)
                IdleService.registerIdleTimerResets()
                TokenService.queueCallbackBeforeExpiry(() => {
                    AuthApiService.postRefreshToken()
                })
                return res
            })
    },
    postLogin({user_name, password }) {
        return fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/auth/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({user_name, password}),
        })
            .then(res =>
                (!res.ok)
                    ? res.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e))
                    : res.json()
            )
                .then(res => {
                    TokenService.saveAuthToken(res.authToken)
                    TokenService.queueCallbackBeforeExpiry(() => {
                        AuthApiService.postRefreshToken()
                    })
                    return res
                })
    },
    postGuestLogin() {
        return fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/auth/guest-login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
        })
            .then(res => 
                (!res.ok)
                    ? res.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e))     
                    : res.json()       
            )
            .then(res => {
                TokenService.saveAuthToken(res.authToken)
                TokenService.queueCallbackBeforeExpiry(() => {
                    AuthApiService.postRefreshToken()
                })
                return res
            })
    },
    postRefreshToken() {
        return fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/auth/refresh`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'authorization': `Bearer ${TokenService.getAuthToken()}`,
            },
        })
            .then(res =>
                (!res.ok)
                    ? res.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e))
                    : res.json()
            )
            .then(res => {
                TokenService.saveAuthToken(res.authToken)
                TokenService.queueCallbackBeforeExpiry(() => {
                    AuthApiService.postRefreshToken()
                })
                return res
            })
            .catch(err => {
                TokenService.clearAuthToken()
                console.log('refresh token request error')
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
}

export default AuthApiService;
```

```js
//TokenService.js

import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import config from '../config';

let _timeoutId;
const _TEN_SECONDS_IN_MS = 10000;

const TokenService = {
  saveAuthToken(token) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(config.TOKEN_KEY, token);
  },
  getAuthToken() {
    return window.localStorage.getItem(config.TOKEN_KEY);
  },
  clearAuthToken() {
    window.localStorage.removeItem(config.TOKEN_KEY);
  },
  hasAuthToken() {
    return !!TokenService.getAuthToken()
  },
  makeBasicAuthToken(userName, password) {
    return window.btoa(`${userName}:${password}`);
  },
  parseJwt(jwt) {
    return jwtDecode(jwt);
  },
  readJwtToken() {
    return TokenService.parseJwt(TokenService.getAuthToken());
  },
  _getMsUntilExpiry(payload) {
    return (payload.exp * 1000) - Date.now();
  },
  queueCallbackBeforeExpiry(callback) {
    const msUntilExpiry = TokenService._getMsUntilExpiry(
      TokenService.readJwtToken()
    );
    _timeoutId = setTimeout(callback, msUntilExpiry - _TEN_SECONDS_IN_MS);
  },
  clearCallbackBeforeExpiry() {
    clearTimeout(_timeoutId);
  }
};

export default TokenService;
```

EDIT:
Here is an example of what the router can look like:

```js
//users-router.js

const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const UsersService = require('./users-service')
const AuthService = require('../auth/auth-service')

const usersRouter = express.Router()
const jsonBodyParser = express.json()

usersRouter.post('/', jsonBodyParser, (req, res, next) => {
    const { password, user_name, full_name } = req.body

    for (const field of ['password', 'full_name', 'user_name'])
        if (!req.body[field])
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: `Missing ${field} in request body`
            })

    const passwordError = UsersService.validatePassword(password)

    if (passwordError)
            return res.status(400).json({ error: passwordError })

    UsersService.hasUserWithUserName(
        req.app.get('db'),
        user_name
    )
        .then(hasUserWithUserName => {
            if(hasUserWithUserName)
                return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Username already taken' })

            return UsersService.hashPassword(password)
                .then(hashedPassword => {
                    const newUser = {
                        user_name,
                        full_name,
                        password: hashedPassword,
                        date_created: 'now()'
                    }

                    return UsersService.insertUser(
                        req.app.get('db'),
                        newUser
                    )
                        .then(user => {
                            const serializedUser = UsersService.serializeUser(user)
                            const { user_name, user_id } = serializedUser
                            const sub = user_name
                            const payload = {user_id: user_id}

                            res
                                .status(201)
                                .location(path.posix.join(req.originalUrl, `/${user.id}`))
                                .send({
                                    authToken: AuthService.createJwt(sub, payload),
                                    user: serializedUser
                                })
                        })
                })
        })
        .catch(next)

})

module.exports = usersRouter
```

```js
//users-service.js

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const xss = require('xss')

const REGEX_UPPER_LOWER_NUMBER_SPECIAL = /(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&])[\S]+/

const UsersService = {
    hasUserWithUserName(db, user_name) {
      return db('askify_users')
        .where({ user_name })
        .first()
        .then(user => !!user)
    },
    insertUser(db, newUser) {
      return db
        .insert(newUser)
        .into('askify_users')
        .returning('*')
        .then(([user]) => user)
    },
    validatePassword(password) {
      if (password.length < 8) {
        return 'Password must be longer than 8 characters'
      }
      if (password.length > 72) {
        return 'Password must be less than 72 characters'
      }
      if (password.startsWith(' ') || password.endsWith(' ')) {
        return 'Password must not start or end with empty spaces'
      }
      if (!REGEX_UPPER_LOWER_NUMBER_SPECIAL.test(password)) {
        return 'Password must contain one upper case, lower case, number and special character'
      }
      return null
    },
    hashPassword(password) {
      return bcrypt.hash(password, 12)
    },
    serializeUser(user) {
      return {
        id: user.id,
        full_name: xss(user.full_name),
        user_name: xss(user.user_name),
        nickname: xss(user.nick_name),
        date_created: new Date(user.date_created),
      }
    },
  }
  
  module.exports = UsersService
```

```js
// auth-service.js

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const config = require('../config')

const AuthService = {
  getUserWithUserName(db, user_name) {
    return db('askify_users')
      .where({user_name})
      .first()
  },
  comparePasswords(password, hash) {
    return bcrypt.compare(password, hash)
  },
  createJwt(subject, payload) {
    return jwt.sign(payload, config.JWT_SECRET, {
      subject,
      expiresIn: config.JWT_EXPIRY,
      algorithm: 'HS256',
    })
  },
  verifyJwt(token) {
    return jwt.verify(token, config.JWT_SECRET, {
      algorithms: ['HS256'],
    })
  },
  parseBasicToken(token) {
    return Buffer
      .from(token, 'base64')
      .toString()
      .split(':')
  },
}

module.exports = AuthService
```